# What does singular hessian in optimization tell me

Tags: numerical-optimization, maximum-likelihood, hessian-matrix

I am doing optimization using maximum likelihood estimation, and when I am trying to get the standard errors of estimates using hessian matrix, I get non-invertible/singular hessian warning.

After I inspect the hessian, I find that there is a column/row of all zeros. What does this tell me? Should I worry about identifiability of my model?

I also have read in the posts that singularity might be caused by precision error, and add $\lambda I$ will fix the problem. But how can I figure it out if my problem is caused by precision in python (I am using float64, and autodifferentiation from jax for hessian)?